# Signification de "pugnacité" dans "Bravo pour ta pugnacité"

Tags: sens, usage

Que signifie pugnacité dans la phrase ci-dessous ?

> Bravo pour ta pugnacité.

**Contexte** : Un collègue a fini par obtenir un poste dans une école d'ingénieurs après plusieurs tentatives sans succès. Un autre collègue l'a félicité en disant "Bravo pour ta pugnacité". Je connais le sens du mot *pugnacité* mais je ne comprends pas son emploi ici.
D'autre part, est-ce un mot courant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ce n'est pas un mot courant, c'est plutôt littéraire, mais ça n'empêche pas qu'il soit très utilisable dans la langue parlée.

> (TLFi) Au fig. Ardeur dans un combat idéologique ou dans la défense d'intérêts.

On trouve à ce mot les synonymes suivants ;

- ardeur, combativité

Le locuteur aurait pu employer le mot « ténacité », qui aurait été, je pense, plus approprié. Il est évident que l'action n'implique pas d'agressivité, de combativité ni même probablement l'attitude de celui qui est opiniâtre.

Ce que cela signifie :

> Je te félicite pour ta constance d'esprit, pour la façon que tu as de croire en tes idées, de ne pas en démordre, pour ta persévérance.

Comment: Pugnacité n'est certes pas un mot utilisé tous les jours par tout le monde mais je ne dirais pas que dans son emploi au sens figuré (dont il est question ici)  il soit « plutôt littéraire ». Je ne pense pas parler comme un livre mais je l'emploie,  et son emploi par un enseignant dans une école d'ingénieur n'a rien de surprenant. Et je ne suis pas d'accord pour accepter agressivité (connotation négative) comme synonyme de pugnacité (connotation positive).

Comment: @Laure Votre usage personnel correspond à peu près à ce que j'appelle « très utilisable dans la langue parlée », mais cependant on ne le trouve que dans le parler d'une classe particulière de personnes, les gens dont l'éducation s'est prolongée dans le supérieur. D'ailleurs le TLFi catégorise le mot comme tel : PUGNACITÉ, subst. fém.
Littér. Propension à combattre et à aimer les luttes corporelles. Je ne suis pas encore assez strict.

Comment: Quand quelqu'un vous dit « bravo pour ta pugnacité » il est évident qu'il s'agit de l'emploi au sens figuré et pas du penchant pour les luttes corporelles !

Comment: @Laure La mention ne couvrirait pas l'acception connexe au figuré selon vous ? Le grand tiret ne signifie-t-il pas que l'on reste dans la même division ?

Comment: @Laure Le Larousse, qui englobe ces deux sens connexes, stipule que c'est un mot littéraire : https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pugnacit%c3%a9/65012?q=pugnacit%c3%a9#64280

Comment: @Laure Je n'avais pas fait attention à ce synonyme donné par le reverso mais je crois bien aussi que ce n'est pas exact; je l'ai enlevé.

Comment: @LPH.          "On ne le trouve que dans le parler d'une classe particulière de personnes, les gens dont l'éducation s'est prolongée dans le supérieur", dites-vous qui avez certainement fait des études supérieures, ce dont je vous félicite.  Mais je vous assure que ce mot est employé également par le bas peuple auquel j'ai l'honneur d'appartenir.  Le ton péremptoire avec lequel vous assénez ce que vous pensez être des vérités finit par lasser.

Comment: @petitrien Pugnacité ? Dans le parler de la rue ? Tous les 36 du mois ! Littéraire dans le TLFi et le Larousse! Vous exagérez évidemment, mieux, vous vous moquez de moi, un « bas peuple bilingue » ! Je ne vais pas vous lasser plus  en assertions péremptoires, dans le présent commentaire …

Comment: Le TLF (excellente référence historique mais datée puisque la dernière mise à jour date de plus de 20 ans) et encore moins le Larousse en ligne (peu fiable en regard d'autres ressources) ne peuvent être considérées comme les uniques références. La langue est une matière vivante qui évolue, qui se parle aussi dans la rue, dans les cours de récré, dans la presse, sur les campus... tout ça fait un magma formidable qui la remet toujours en question. Bref, il faut aussi écouter autour de soi et nuancer.

Comment: @Laure Je vais quand même m'en tenir au TLFi (et au Larousse) et considérer que « pugnacité » est plutôt littéraire; quant à « nuancer » je ne vois pas ce que cela veut dire : il n'y a rien à introduire dans la fabrique des choses qui n'y soit déjà pour en définir leur identité. De plus je ne crois pas que vingt cinq années d'évolution d'une langue qui devient de plus en plus argotique et s'éloigne de ses racines soient allées dénicher le mot « pugnacité » de son cercueil littéraire pour en faire un mot de la rue.

Comment: Merci. C'est vingt-cinq, avec trait d'union, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: @Dimitris Oui, je suis allé trop vite, j'aurais dû vérifier ça : vingt-cinq.

Comment: Peut-être le mot est plus courant qu'auparavant : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pugnacit%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpugnacit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Je viens de faire un googling avec la phrase complète "bravo pour ta pugnacité". Il s'emploie dans des e-mails ou messages sur Facebook même dans un contexte relâché.

Comment: @Dimitris Il n'y a pas de doute, il l'est, mais dans la langue écrite ; c'est peut être dû au besoin de traduire l'anglais américain « agressivity » qui est devenu très courant en américain. Attention, « agressive » en américain ne signifie pas « agressif » en français (mais vous savez peut être déjà).

Comment: @LPH Je viens de donner une réponse. Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Comment: @Dimitris Bonne trouvaille ! Je crois que le sens figuré reconnu depuis longtemps est toujours plus ou moins valable dans cette nouvelle mode. Il ne s'agirait pas d'un sens vraiment nouveau.

Comment: @LPH Je viens de l'éditer. Merci pour les échanges:-)!

Answer (score 2):

Complèment à l'autre réponse. Je pense que le mot pugnacité a obtenu il y a quelque temps un sens pas éloigné de celui dans les dictionnaires mais moins littéraire.

La définition "classique" est :

> Sens 1 Littéraire Combativité, concerne une personne aimant polémiquer
>   et se battre afin d'atteindre ses objectifs. Relatif à un homme ou une
>   femme au fort caractère qui n'a pas peur des actions fortes pour
>   arriver à ses fins. https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/pugnacite/

(ou bien https://jolismots.fr/pugnacite/#)

Langage parlé ou écrit, locuteurs "bien éduqués" ou pas, on l'utilise plutôt (je crois n'étant pas locuteur natif) avec le sens ci-dessous :

> "La pugnacité est probablement la qualité principale de
>   l'entrepreneur", estime Sandra Le Grand, présidente de Kalidea ."Quand
>   une porte se ferme, passez par la fenêtre, pour parvenir à vos fins.
>   Soyez toujours dans une logique de séduction, n'abandonnez jamais",
>   juge-elle. Pour David Layani, PDG du Groupe Onepoint, la pugnacité est
>   la clé du succès. "Sans elle, il n'y a pas d'entrepreneur. Il faut un
>   grand rêve et la ferme intention de ne pas s'arrêter avant la ligne
>   d'arrivée qui recule toujours", dit-il. Evelyne Platnic Cohen,
>   dirigeante de Booster Academy est sur la même longueur d'onde que les
>   autres dirigeants. Selon elle, "l'entrepreneur va chercher du business
>   et ne lâche rien. Il faut avoir la vision de son portefeuille qui ne
>   doit jamais se tarir. On est donc à la recherche permanente de
>   clients".
>
> https://www.journaldunet.com/management/creation-entreprise/1168690-15-qualites-incontournables-pour-etre-un-super-entrepreneur/1168914-pugnacite

(Dans le même esprit, https://www.bilan.ch/economie/_la_cle_du_succes_la_pugnacite_)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pugnacit%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpugnacit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0) indique que le mot est plus courant qu'auparavant.
[Une langue doit évoluer pour être vivante :-)!](http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2017/11/24/37003-20171124ARTFIG00013-une-langue-doit-evoluer-pour-etre-vivante.php)

Comment: C'est bien ce que je pensais, il traduisent l'américain « agressivity ».

Comment: « Défendre ses intérêts » et  « se battre afin d'atteindre ses objectifs » ne sont pas des idées très différentes l'une de l'autre; vous pensez qu'il s'agit d'un vraiment nouveau sens ? En quoi ?

Comment: Peut-être j'exagère:-) ! Comme je dis ce que je pense. J'ai voulu mettre en avant que le sens courant et celui de la felicitation de mon collègue n'ont rien à faire (je crois n'étant pas locuteur natif) avec "...concerne une personne aimant polémiquer et se battre afin d'atteindre ses objectifs." qu'on trouve dans les dictionnaires.

Comment: C'est ce qui me semblait aussi, représenter une candidature plusieurs fois ne parait pas relever d'un comportement autre que assez passif, à moins qu'il y ait eu des démarches spéciales de faite dans le sens de produire des références plus solides et de démontrer une aptitude particulière; dans ce dernier cas, le terme serait alors justifié pleinement.